# How to add cyrillic text to tikz image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, cyrillic

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, shapes, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (10pt, 50pt) {Й};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and compiled with

```
xelatex test.tex
```

But the output is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whether you're drawing a `tikzpicture` or not, you should load `fontspec` and a font that supports Cyrillic:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, shapes, arrows}
\begin{document}
Андре́й Арсе́ньевич Тарко́вский — советский кинорежиссёр и сценарист. Народный артист РСФСР.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (10pt, 50pt) {Й};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```