# Why doesn't \usepackage{times} work with cyrillic characters?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, characters, cyrillic

I need to add some text to my LaTeX document, I need to use `Times New Roman` font, and that text contains cyrillic characters.

I tried using `times` package:

```
\usepackage{times}
```

but that simply omits cyrillic chars.

I tried using fontspec:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
```

but that gives me error:

```
kpathsea: Invalid fontname `Times New Roman', contains ' '
! Font EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/24.88="Times New Roman:mapping=tex-text;" at 24
.88pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Just a guess: try `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson - I tried it with both versions, still the same errors.

Comment: There's no support in the main distributions for cyrillic Times under pdfLaTeX. So `\usepackage{times}` doesn't work. You may be luckier with `\usepackage{paratype}`. The font isn't Times, though. See http://www.paratype.com

Comment: @egreg - There's this problem - I need *exactly* times. It's not a style issue - I need to follow guidelines.

Comment: @egreg - So there's totally no way to have text typeset with Times in latex?

Comment: If you have a Times system font with cyrillic support, you can use XeLaTeX. Difficult to say without more information about your set up.

Comment: @egreg - I compile with `xelatex file.tex` usually. I have `texlive` distibution installed (quite an old version, though - `2009`. I thought that upgrading my system will upgrade texlive as well, seems it didn't). Also, I have no idea what fonts my system has - Libreoffice works with cyrillic Times without any problems - does that mean that I indeed have that font?

Comment: Also, `times.sty` is deprecated. One should use `mathptmx.sty` instead. Not that I think it helps with *your* problem, mind you. The Times font that your LibreOffice sees is probably [Nimbus Roman No9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Roman_No9_L) or [Liberation Serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_Serif) if you're on Linux/*BSD and some commercial version if you're on Windows or OSX.

Comment: Furthermore, you should *really* update your TeXLive install. Fontspec has seen many improvements since 2009.

Comment: @kahen - I checked in LibreOffice, and indeed `Liberation Serif` in it is indistinguishable from `Times New Roman` - yet it still seems to view them as different fonts. Using `\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}` in my latex file seems to give me proper font. Thanks a lot! About old TeXLive - `2009` is the latest version in ubuntu repositories, for some reason they do not update it. What would be the best way to update my TeXLive install in this situation?

Comment: tl2009 _isn't_ the latest in the ubuntu repositories.  however, ubuntu 12.04 is the latest lts version (default install in my dept), and predates tl2012.  so (of course?) tl2009 remains the current one for lts installs.  ubuntu 12.10 _does_ have tl2012 (aiui), and i've been told there's a backport tl2012 bundle for ubuntu 12.04

Comment: One can also use the TeXLive netinstall and use the `dpkg` features that let you tell the system "I've manually installed so-and-so packages". This is covered in one of the linked pages [from here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). After completing a TeXLive netinstall and setting up the `equivs` for it, one would then go and add the relevant directories to the `PATH` and `MANPATH` in `/etc/environment` (note this is *not* a shell script, it's a plain text config file), reboot and everything should be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, it's crucial to update your TeX distribution first (some people would even say: don't even think about asking a question without having updated your distribution first).

As you seem to be using XeLaTeX, loading fonts via packages made for pdfTeX isn't the best option in most cases. You should really be using `fontspec` IMHO.

I'm sure your operating system already includes Times New Roman -- not necessarily under that name, though, and not necessarily a version that includes Cyrillic. One version that definitely does is the one shipped with Windows. [Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34077/libreoffice-missing-certain-microsoft-fonts) how to install it, in case it's not available on your machine yet. Once it is, something like this should work without any problems (unless something more fundamental is wrong with your TeX system):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
Рома́н О́сипович Якобсо́н — российский и американский лингвист и литературовед,
один из крупнейших лингвистов XX века, оказавший влияние на развитие гуманитарных
наук не только своими новаторскими идеями, но и активной организаторской деятельностью.
\end{document}
```

[image]

A few other Cyrillic-aware fonts that can be used with `fontspec` are listed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115037/7993).

Comment: One could also use the STIX/XITS fonts or the Free Serif from the GNU Free Fonts package. They are all based on the Times outlines and contain kyrillic characters.

Answer (score 2):

For usage with `pdflatex` there is `tempora`, which provides support for a Times like font in the Latin, Greek and Cyrillic alphabets.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{tempora}% for text
\usepackage{newtxmath}% for math

\begin{document}

Роман Осипович Якобсон — российский и американский лингвист и литературовед,
один из крупнейших лингвистов XX века, оказавший влияние на развитие гуманитарных
наук не только своими новаторскими идеями, но и активной организаторской деятельностью.
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2)\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using XeLaTeX, I managed to get everything working fine after a while.

The main idea is to get rid of babel in favour of polyglossia. First, you remove these lines as they won't let you use polyglossia adequately:

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
```

Then you configure polyglossia. This is a bit more verbose than with babel, but it is worth it:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian} % change this if the order of languages is different 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman} 
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX] % this is needed for << to be converted into «
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontrm}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{Arial}
\setkeys{russian}{babelshorthands=true}
```

Worked for me after everything else failed.