# How to write a document on cyrillic?

Tags: languages

I tried the instructions from the how to solve the problem [reference link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115027/how-to-add-cyrillic-text-to-tikz-image?newreg=f589da3e06cb4ee2941667751059fa7b), but it doesn't work. I installed package as well and I really can't find a way to write my documents in Cyrillic.
What should I do/write in order to use this font_

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Cyrillic is not a language, but an alphabet. What language would you write the document in?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it's an alphabet.
I would like to write in Serbian :)

Answer (score 1):

Serbian is no different from other languages except that it can be written with two scripts, Cyrillic and Latin.

The documentation for `babel-serbianc` (the `c` stands for Cyrillic) has a sample document in the `report` class, but the setup should work for any class.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\title{Пример ћирилично-latiničnog документа}
\author{Филип Брчић <brcha@users.sourceforge.net>}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Азбука}

А Б В Г Д Ђ Е Ж З И Ј К Л Љ М Н Њ О П Р С Т Ћ У Ф Х Ц Ч Џ Ш

а б в г д ђ е ж з и ј к л љ м н њ о п р с т ћ у ф х ц ч џ ш

\chapter{Abeceda}

A B C Č Ć D Dž Đ E F G H I J K L Lj M N Nj O P R S Š T U V Z Ž

a b c č ć d dž đ e f g h i j k l lj m n nj o p r s š t u v z ž

\end{document}
```

### Title page

[image]

### First chapter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Always compiling with `pdfLaTeX`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

Я не знаю, имеет ли этот перевод смысл на русском языке.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\cyrtext[1]{{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont #1}}
\begin{document}

\cyrtext{ДёжзКклЪЩЧщ}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
ФЦцшыЭЮЯноОН
\end{document}
```

[image]